# PostgreSQL backup on Linux

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Is there a way to backup a PostgreSQL database from one server to another? I've seen that you can do a backup with pg_dump and you can use this command into a cron expression by i haven't seen if you can use this command to backup a database from an server, and move automatically the backup into another server.

Answer (score 0):

`pg_dump` is a client program, so you can run it on any machine that has network connectivity to the PostgreSQL server.

For backup purposes, you should run it on a different machine or at least make sure that the backup ends up on different storage.

Use the `-h` option to specify the database server name and `-p` for the port.

Answer (score 0):

after backup you can copy backup file to remote server with `scp` utility

```
pg_dump mydb > db.sql
scp db.sql username@to_host:/remote/directory/
```